# Hide rows where cells in Column C are '0'

Tags: vba, excel

I need a VBA code to hide all rows that contain the cipher `0` in column C. 
I'm currently using the filter option but would like to hide them without the filter option. Here is a picture of my sheet for example:

[image]

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831347/vba-macro-excel-how-to-hide-rows-if-cell-equal-false?rq=1) Might help you

Comment: Can you not just use a filter to hide all those rows with `0`?

Comment: @BruceWayne - `I'm currently using the filter option but would like to hide them without the filter option`

Comment: *slowly backs away*. Sorry, my brain skipped that completely

Comment: OP -> please review [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive better help on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this:

```
Sub hideCells()
Dim lastRow&
Dim cel As Range, rng As Range

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range(Cells(6, 3), Cells(lastRow, 3))

For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Value = "0" Then
        cel.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

A quick thought though - using a Macro to hide these may be not quite the way you want to go.  Why don't you want to use Filter?  I say this because a macro a) can't be undone, b) isn't dynamic really (whereas a filter can easily unhide them), and c) you'll have a Macro workbook which isn't totally necessary.  Just a thought though.

And of course, to reverse that (to unhide the cells), just use the same macro, but change to `cel.EntireRow.Hidden = False`.

Comment: i don't want to use the filter option because it will not let me paste over a merged cell and you can't edit the hidden rows when it's enabled, but when hiding rows without the filter option you can drag a cell down and it also applies to the hidden ones

Comment: @luke - Ah, yeah merged cells can be annoying, and I see now why no Filter - makes sense.  Although, (sorry, not to be pedantic) is there no way you are able to paste over the range *before* filtering?  Anyways, the above code should work AFAIK.

Comment: unfortunately no at lest no fast way that i know of, i will end up with 20+ sheets that i select all at once and then paste values only over the entire sheets to remove all the formulas and then delete all the costs so that only the selling prices are showing. but the code you gave me is working thank you.

Comment: Check out the thread on the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Not saying we have one here, but perhaps there's a better method to do what you're trying to in general.  Just food for thought.  But, I'm glad the above worked!